# jQuery - Copyingclasses from one element to another IF conditions are correct

Tags: jquery, class, element, transfer

Basic idea of what im after..

On document ready copy classes from "#box-one" into "#box-three" **if** "#box-two img" has the same image name as "#box-one img"

and if possible.. with the possibility of excluding specific classes from transferring

html:

```
<span id="box-one" class="first second third">
   <img src="imagefolder/image1.jpg" alt />
</span>

<span id="box-two">
   <img src="imagefolder2/image1.jpg" alt />
</span>

<span id="box-three"></span>
```

Keeping in mind that the images inside "#box-one" and "#box-two" change but are always identical.

I have no idea how to do this as far as the js goes.. How could this be done?

Comment: Uh...  use an `if` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var classesToIgnore = ["second"];

    if($("#box-one > img").attr("src").split('/').pop() == $("#box-two > img").attr("src").split('/').pop()) {
       //Get all classes into an array
       var classes = $("#box-one").attr("class").split(" ");
       //Grep out the classes you dont want and join it into a string seperated by space
       classes = $.grep(classes, function(class, index){
           return ($.inArray(class, classesToIgnore));
       }).join(" ");
       //Overwrite #box-three's classes. If you want to append them, loop over the array and use $("#box-three").addClass("className");
       $("#box-three").attr("class", classes);
    }

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/raPBy/

Comment: this works nicely but theres one thing.. if the folders are different this doesnt work.

http://jsfiddle.net/xekBx/1/ ( i just changed the other imagefolder name )

Its basically like big image and thumbnail image that have same name but are in different folders.

Comment: Explain what you mean by the name of the image, as your HTML example doesn't specify anything apart from the src.

Comment: <img src="imagefolder/image1.jpg" alt />  
 <img src="imagefolder2/image1.jpg" alt />
 these have different folders

Answer (score 2):

This will add all of the classes from box one to box three, and clear the class of box one. If you want to move specific classes, you can use the jQuery methods `$.addClass` and `$.removeClass`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var box1 = $('#box-one'),
      box2 = $('#box-two'),
      box3 = $('#box-three'),
      className = box1.attr('class');

  if(box1.find('img').attr('src') === box2.find('img').attr('src')) {
      box3.addClass(className);
      box1.attr('class', '');
  }
});
```

**Edit**

You can compare just the filename segment using:

```
var src1 = $('#box-one').attr('src').split('/').pop(),
    src2 = $('#box-two').attr('src').split('/').pop();
```

Comment: This answer works except, from looking at the HTML example, the images appear to be in different folders. If only file names need to be the same, you would need to get `.attr('src')` then get only the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('#box-two img').attr('alt') == $('#box-one img').attr('alt')){//can use attr('src')
   $('#box-three').addClass($('#box-one').attr('class'));
    $('#box-one').removeClass();//if u want to remove class from #box-one
  }
});
```

Comment: this seems to work nicely except i chose my words poorly as i really meant copying the classes rather than transferring...

Comment: nevermind.. took me a while to realize what you did there.. its all good.